# How can the products page be changed?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, rwd-theme, design, product-page

I have my own theme derived from the default RWD theme in 1.9.2.1. However, I want to change the products page. so, it looks like figure one rather than the defualt rwd one with the tabs.  However, im not the biggest expert in magento and have no idea how to go about doing, so was wondering if anyone could guide me to what I have to?

figure 1:
[image: figure 1]

Comment: A similar post here might help you get started http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40479/magento-custom-product-page-design-and-custom-options

Comment: I have gottten my custom page view to display for the product. Now, I just need to figure out how to get the elements to show. E.g. product images and so forth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File: app/design/frontend/Your-package/Your-Theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

your product detail page content coming from above file.

Product images from:

app/design/frontend/Your-package/Your-Theme/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml

Also you need to check xml file to adjust block placement

app/design/frontend/Your-package/Your-Theme/layout/catalog.xml

Using below code you can add related product on product view page

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('related_products') ?>
```

Comment: thanks, I am aware of those locations. However, would you happen to know how I can add the related and recommended products again ?

Comment: I have updated code using this code you can show related product on product view page

Comment: Ah yes sorry I managed to solve it. Just working on videos now and construct a good solution.

Comment: If it helps you then mark as accepted.